# securing a string method - controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I return "~/Error/Unauthorized" page if a user is not admin and tries to access certain controllers. Here is how I return the error page:

```
            if (!Models.Authorization.AdminPageCheck(this.User))
            return new RedirectResult("~/Error/Unauthorized");
```

I am able to do it for ActionResult methods, but not for string methods as it doesn't return a view. How can I secure a string method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change those methods to return `ActionResult`s.
You can then `return Content(someText, "content/type")`

Answer (score 5):

It's preferable to use ASP.NET MVC's built-in capability, and just annotate your Controller (either at the class level, for all actions, or at the action method level) with

```
[Authorize]
```

In the event that someone tries to call a method and they are not logged in, they'll be forced to authenticate using the method configured in web.config.

Or, if you use

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AdminRole")]
```

They'll be forced to authenticate, if they're not already, then they'll be granted or denied access based on them having the relevant role.

It's a very common requirement and thankfully, the ASP.NET MVC Team have dealt with it very comprehensively!

Answer (score 0):

If you sometimes have a different outcome than just a string, then the preferred "fix" there would be: don't return `string`; return `ActionResult`, and when it *is* the string,

```
return Content(yourString);
```

Optionally specifying a content-type / encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks mentioned, you can change the return type of the string methods to ActionResult, then use the [ContentResult class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) to return a string.